# Making a call button that calls phone number of searched location

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a UI button on a callout of a annotation of a searched location. I want the button to call the phone number of the location/business.

Here's my code:

```
func doCall()
{
    if let selectedPin = selectedPin
    {
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
            if mapItem.phoneNumber != nil
                {
                    let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "telprompt://" + (mapItem.phoneNumber!))
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Cant Call")
                    print(mapItem.phoneNumber)

                }

    }
}
```

It's always returning "Cant Call"

I am able to access the phone number of a location that is searched through this code:

```
extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let mapView = mapView,
    let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
    // Change line above to find nearby places
    request.region = mapView.region
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, _ in
        if let items = response?.mapItems
        {
            for item in items
            {
                if let coordinates = item.placemark.location?.coordinate
                {
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = coordinates
                    annotation.title = item.name
                    annotation.subtitle = item.phoneNumber
                    self.mapView!.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            }
        }
        guard let response = response else {
            return
        }


        self.matchingItems = response.mapItems

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

How do embed the code directly above into my doCall method to make the UI Button proceed with the call?

Any help would be appreciated...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is that `open(url:options:)` (**3.x**) or `openURL` (**2.2**) cannot handle phone numbers with spaces, ( ), - and other characters in them that you will find with the `mapItem`.

Updated answer for **Swift 3.x**:

```
func doCall() {
    if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
        if let phoneNumber = mapItem.phoneNumber?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: ""),
            let url = URL(string: "telprompt://" + phoneNumber) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            print("Unable to call because number is nil")
        }
    }
}
```

Original answer for **Swift 2.2**:

```
func doCall() {
    if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
        if let phoneNumber = (mapItem?.phoneNumber?.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet))?.joinWithSeparator("") {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://" + phoneNumber)!)
        } else {
            print("Unable to call because number is nil")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this works fine for me:

```
if let phoneNumber = user!.phoneNumber, url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code that you wrote, "Can't call" would only be printed if the `mapItem.phoneNumber` is `nil`.

Let's take a look:

```
// Create a variable holding a new `MKMapItem` type.
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)

// Compare the `phoneNumber` property of `mapItem` against `nil`.
// If it's not `nil`, then proceed to open the telephones using the URL. 
if mapItem.phoneNumber != nil
{
    let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "tel://" + (mapItem.phoneNumber!))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
else
{
    // If you end up here, then `mapItem.phoneNumber` was nil. 
    print("Cant Call")
    print(mapItem.phoneNumber)

}
```

Try using the debugger in Xcode to set a breakpoint. Inspect `mapItem.phoneNumber` to see the value of the items. See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9vAsEWRsOM